# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'u.requestPermissions')

Tags: react-native, react-native-fcm

I am trying to use FCM push notification in my react native app. I am stuck at this point where i have imported FCM but still it says "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'u.requestPermissions')"

I have imported the lib and also linked to my project.

[Done exactly as mentioned in this README.md file](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm)

[image: This is the error i'm getting.]